# mouse-click event binding with Tkinter seems to act one-step slower than expected

Tags: python, tkinter, events, click, bind

I am practicing an event-binding with Tkinter.
A fundamental mouse-click event (not double-click) seems strange at least to me.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
def change(event): 
    sel = Listbox0.curselection()    
    print(sel)
    for val in sel:
        if val == 0: 
            root.configure(background='red') 
        elif val == 1: 
            root.configure(background='green') 
        elif val == 2: 
            root.configure(background='yellow') 
   
   
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('250x275') 
   
Listbox0 = Listbox(root, height=3) 
Listbox0.insert(0, 'Red') 
Listbox0.insert(1, 'Green') 
Listbox0.insert(2, 'Yellow') 

Listbox0.bind('<Button-1>', change) 
Listbox0.pack() 

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, my code is supposed to change the background color according to the selected one on the listbox. It works, however, one-step slowerly. First when I click any item just right after the main loop runs, nothing happens. After that, every time I click any item, the background changes but to the color I clicked just previously. I have a clue by print(sel) in function but no clue how I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the callback function is executed before the default handler of `Listbox`.  So when the callback function is executed, the selection is not set yet because it is set by the default handler.

You can bind on `<ButtonRelease-1>` or `<<ListboxSelect>>` instead.